# mongo document index annotation doesnt work

Tags: mongodb, annotations, doctrine, doctrine-odm

why the index creation (properthy testId) doesnt work? I've tried it via annotation. Can somebody help in this case?

```
 /**
 * @ODM\Field(type="string")
 * @ODM\Index(unique=true, order="asc")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type(
 *     type="string",
 *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
 * )
 */
public $testId;
```

Comment: Firstly are you able to connect and able to insert data into mongo collections ?

Comment: yes, i have also a auto increment id, this works fine

Answer (score 0):

Annotation just lets ODM know that you want an index, you need to actually create it. By `@Assert` usage I assume you're a Symfony user, so just run `./bin/console odm:schema:create --index`

Full docs on indexes can be found here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.1/reference/indexes.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly the console command dont work. 

Error: There are no commands defined in the "odm:schema" namespace.  
                                                                
  Did you mean one of these?                                    
      api:json-schema                                           
      doctrine:schema                                           
      orm                                                       
      orm:convert